# Presenting Lists item in detail sheet swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a viewModel that with an item and a child view, I also present a sheet from a View and pass a selected item to that view. This in turn makes the selected item = item in the child view. The problem now is I have to dismiss the sheet and select a desired item be the value changes in the child view. This is a weird behaviour any help would be appreciated

My view Model

```
class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Injected(\.itemLocalRepository) var itemLocalRepository: ItemLocalRepository
    @Published var items: [Item] { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
    
    init(shoppingList: ShoppingList) {

      self.shoppingList = shoppingList.item
      // Printing shoppingList prints default value before changing to desired on on second selection
    }

}
```

// Main View

```
struct FrequentView: View {
    @State var selectedShoppingList: ShoppingList = ShoppingList.single
    @State private var presentCreateSheet: Bool = false
    var itemsList = [...]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, pinnedViews: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/[]/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, content: {
                        ForEach(itemsList, id: \.id) { shoppingList in
                            Button {
                                self.selectedShoppingList = shoppingList
                                self.presentCreateSheet = true
                            } label: {
                                HomeRowView(shoppingList: shoppingList)
                            }
                            Divider()
                                .padding(.top, 0)
                        }
                    })
                })
                    
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentCreateSheet, onDismiss: {
                Task.init {
                    await viewModel.getList()
                }
                self.presentCreateSheet = false
            }, content: {
                ItemView(viewModel: ItemViewModel(shoppingList: selectedShoppingList))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:)` instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`

Comment: Would item still be `$presentCreateSheet`?

Comment: No -- you'll want to have an Optional. Probably `selectedShoppingList`, but don't have `single` selected by default -- have it be `nil`

Comment: How is the sheet triggered now please? Content of the sheet does not seem to appear.

Comment: It should look something like this: `.sheet(item: selectedItem) { item in ItemView(viewModel: ItemViewModel(shoppingList: item))`

Comment: @jnpdx it shows now but my navigation bar Items are not clickable.

Comment: You'd need to show the relevant code in order for me to try to debug that.

Comment: I asked here. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049957/navigation-bar-item-not-clickable-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment123829532_70049957

Comment: I already answered there that it wasn't reproducible for me, unfortunately. Does the code you included there depend on it being in the sheet from this question?

Comment: It is the itemView that I presented.

Comment: What I'm asking is: does the button issue *only* happen when it's presented in a sheet? In other words, do you still see the issue if you *only* use the code you presented in the other question, or does it *depend on* the code here?

Comment: Any code presented actually. I experience the same issue.

Comment: So from presenting this sheet here, the navigation buttons are not clickable. What I noticed is I have to use a normal button to click. For example if I am navigating to another view, I have to use a normal button first then if I press back, the navigation bar burrow becomes active.